# why am i getting org.apache.jasper.JasperException?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

When i run the following servlet :

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
    Bean bean = new Bean(); 
    bean.setName("Suhail Gupta");
    request.setAttribute("Name", bean);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

an exception :

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6054: Cannot find any information on property 'Name' in a bean of type 'Bean'

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.
```

is generated. I don't understand the reason for this.

Following is the *Bean* class :

```
public class Bean {

private String Name = null;

public void setName(String n) {
    Name = n;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;        
  }
}
```

and this is the `index.jsp` page :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="name" class="Bean" scope="request" />
    Person created by the Servlet : <jsp:getProperty name="name" property="Name" />
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to find the reason for the exception.

Comment: Try using `name` instead of `Name` for the member in class `Bean` and the attribute name in `Controller`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the property should be lowercase `private String name` - this is dictated by the java convention and the javabeans standard
- the tag should use lowercase `property="name"` - javabeans, again
- the name of the bean should not be `Name`, this is confusing. Make it `nameBean` (lowercase, preferably)
- your class should have a package. default package causes problems.
- instead of `jsp:` tags you can simply use EL: `${nameBean.name}` would resolve to the proper value.

Comment: yes ! the problem is resolved. _(The problem set also included the default package !.)_  But i get `null` where i expect the name set by `bean.setName("Suhail Gupta")`. What could be the reason for this ?